# Appscript: Renaming a URL link

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet using Appscript set up so it will return the link for auto generated Google doc however instead of displaying the link I would like it to be a hyperlink off of one of the data in a column.

This is the current script for it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QrC5.png)

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to stackoverflow! Please add the code in the question instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

To create a hyperlink in a Google Sheet using Apps Script, you can use the **setFormula** method to set the formula for the cell, which will create a hyperlink based on the provided URL and display text.

Here's an example based on a URL returned by **doc.getUr1**:

```
doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUr1();
const cell = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1);
cell.setFormula(`=HYPERLINK("${url}", "Link Text")`);
```

Comment: I have now changed it to that but have  replaced “Link Text” with row[30]) as this is what I want the name to be called and it is returning with #ERROR! on the sheet

Comment: I have fixed this so it now called row[30] however I want it to display the info in row[30] instead